# Aviary SDK Integration in maven android project

Tags: android, maven, aviary

I want to use **aviary** **SDK** into **maven** android project .I did not find any dependecy in **maven** central repositories regarding **aviary** **sdk**. Please help me .

Thanks

Comment: Thanks ademar for correction.